# pip of python installed via deadsnakes, shows "no module named distutils" error

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, distutils

When installing python using deadsnakes ppa, and using pip on it like in the following example

```bash
python3.12 -m pip install django
```

will result in the following error

```bash
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Run

```bash
sudo apt install python3.12-distutils
```

and this should solve your problem InshaAllah

## Long Answer

When installing any python version using the deadsnakes ppa, you won't install an important package called distutils which is required for pip to run, if you have any other version other than python3.12, than use the following format

```py
sudo apt install python{version}-distutils
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that `distutils` was in the standard library until Python 3.12, which is why `pip` assumes it will be available and why `python3.12-distutils` needs to exist.

Comment: Rather than install `distutils`, I would try updating `pip` first. Without `distutils`, you might try using an older version of Python.